# Can't find @angular/common/http on stackblitz

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I try to create a new service file on Stackblitz, for some reason I get an error message: Can't find module '@angular/common/http'

Same with 'rxjs/Observable'; any idea why? It uses now Angular 6.

I have the @angular/http under npm packages

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `@angular/http` package to the dependencies.
[image]

Then in your main module:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ ..., HttpClientModule],
  ...
})
```

---

It's rxjs 6, imports are simplified:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
```

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I forgot to put the HttpClientModule in the imports array.

Comment: Can u please help me on the same issue.. I am using the ViusalStudio and creating the service call from it.But some reason not getting the `import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
` Can u please help me on it